# Is there any particular difference between "source code" and "translation unit"?

Tags: c++

I know source code is what we write as a code and translation unit includes a source file and source files included via directive. Then what is the difference between the two?

Comment: So your question is "I know X is defined as Y and Z, but what is the difference between X and Y?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Translation unit" refers to a particular *structure* made out of source code. You organize your source code into headers and implementation files, then you construct translation units out of those files, then you construct programs out of translation units.

Perhaps an analogy would help:

bridge : steel beam : steel

::

program : translation unit : source code